# Rails 4.2 app very slow in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, autoload

I've been banging my head against the wall on that one for a couple of days now.
My app is running super slow in development mode. A good amount of time is spent on serving the assets (especially images). Each request is extremely slow, taking up to 7s to load a simple 50kb jpeg. Total page load time can be up to a couple of minutes...

I suspect there is a link with auto-loading of the code, since when I turn on classes caching my stuff is loaded much much faster (a few hundred ms maximum). That's not a solution though, since I need to be coding, I can't restart the server everytime I make a change.

Here's my config/development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 3000 }
  # email sending process
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  # Defaults to:
  # config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  #   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  #   arguments: '-i -t'
  # }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'no-reply@example.com'}
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = '0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0'


end
```

and initializers/assets.rb

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.Jcrop.min.scss )
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.Jcrop.min.js )
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( flat-ui.css.bak )
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootsrap.css.map)
# Add additional assets to the asset load path
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.scss, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does a brand new app demonstrate the same behaviour? What about requesting single assets? What method are you using for launching the app? What operating system are you on? These files you've posted here have almost nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Can you try with `config.assets.debug = true` in `development.rb` ?

Comment: Try precompiling assets, sometimes it helps

Answer (score 1):

Many issues can happens in your application, for example it can be N+1 queries or some slow code, HTTP queries into other site or big assets bundle. So I suggest use profiler it will show bottleneck in your code. See list popular profilers below:

https://github.com/glassechidna/stackprofiler

https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof

Other helpful links you can find here:

https://awesome-ruby.com/#-profiler-and-optimization